# How to use letters in MARIE?

Tags: assembly

Does anyone know how you can use letters and not numbers in [MARIE](http://computerscience.jbpub.com/ecoa/2e/student_resources.cfm)? I need to make it output a letter like "r" depending on what the users input, but I have no idea how MARIE use letters.

Comment: all letters are numbers. the ASCII code for 'r' is 82 (52 hex)

Answer (score 2):

MARIE doesn't seem to support characters in its assmebler language. Instead, you must enter the [ASCII character codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) as integers. As an example, see this excerpt from [this reference guide](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~fienup/cs041s11/lectures/Supplement_MARE_AL.pdf):

```
STR,   DEC  72   / H
       DEC  69   / E
       DEC  76   / L
       DEC  76   / L
       DEC  79   / O
       DEC  13   / carriage return
       DEC  87   / W
       DEC  79   / O
       DEC  82   / R
       DEC  76   / L
       DEC  68   / D
       DEC  0    / NULL CHAR
```

Answer (score 0):

To get letters as output in MARIE

1. goto OUTPUT console
2. Find the drop-down on the bottom left in OUTPUT (is says DEC by default)
3. Select ASCII from the drop-down
4. Any data in the OUTPUT window will immediately be displayed in ASCII